# Retrieving the name of the class which powers a model field

Tags: django, django-1.3

I'm handling some edge cases in some django code, and i'm hitting a problem that is only encountered when specific fields are involved.

I want to be able to detect the class that the Model is using for a field and depending upon the result drop into alternate logic.

I've tried to use `get_internal_type()` on the field instance but it just returns `"BooleanField"` and not the expected `"ModifiedField"`

The Custom Field Type:

```
class ModifiedField(models.BooleanField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['editable'] = False
        models.BooleanField.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        value = getattr(model_instance, self.attname)

        if add:
            return True
        elif value == 2:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Model:

```
class TemplateItem(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), upload_to=_template_image_upload_path,
                              storage=item_fs, null=True, blank=True)
    is_modified = ModifiedField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried **class**._*name*_ ??

```
g = TemplateItem.objects.get(id=1)
g.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: Actually the op is looking for a model's *field* class, not the class of the model itself.

Comment: Thank you, I feel kind of stupid now for not remembering I can do this!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers is right I do want the field class, but if you have an instance of the class like I do, then it is simply a case of calling `instance.__class__.__name__`

Answer (score 0):

```
fld_cls = type(model_instance._meta.get_field(fieldname))
```